# How can I parse flags in command line argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, command-line-arguments

I have to implement a --pos flag in Python and create a new condition if it exists, but argparse does not recognize it when I enter it in the command line argument.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('lang', type=str, help='Language')
parser.add_argument('mode', help='the mode you want to output the results with')
parser.add_argument('flag', help='the flag that triggers pos-tags')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

So when I run the command:

```
python3 pi.py en lemma --pos
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: --pos
```

Is there a way to catch that flag as a third argument?

Comment: Try changing `'flag'` for `'--pos'`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to pass `--pos` in command line but handle it as `flag` internally...? The flag style parsing is explained in argparse's [Introducing Optional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#introducing-optional-arguments).

Comment: @Ralubrusto Close. That will require an argument to the flag. You also need to add `action='store_true'`. See [Ruggero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65118479/4518341).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are defining a "positional argument" which is not what you want. If you want to implement a flag (true/false) `--pos` just do that.

```
...
parser.add_argument('--pos', action='store_true', help='the flag that triggers pos-tags')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.pos:
    ...
```

and call it as

```
python3 pi.py en lemma --pos
```

Comment: Also note that the flag can go anywhere on the command line, so for example `python3 pi.py --pos en lemma` will also work. Just mentioning in case OP's confused.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works like a charm. I did try to change 'flag' to '--pos' earlier but it didn't work either. Now with the 'action='store_true'', it works!